# Can't upload few images with form in django

Tags: python, django, forms, formset

I have django app (django 1.6) and I have problem to send few images, to upload few images. On front-end side this is OK, I can drag and drop images and see them there.

The problem starts when I push save button. From few images uploaded in front-end side, now I can see only one. So, for example, from 2 uploaded images in front-end, now I can see only one.

Here is html where I'm uploading images:

```
<ul class="uploads">
{% for formset in forms%}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for a in formset %}
        {% if 'can_edit_posts' in perm_list or a.attachment.value %}
        <li class="{% if not a.attachment.value %}empty{% endif %}" data-form-name="{{ a.attachment.html_name }}">
            {{ a.id }}{{ a.post_locale }}

            {{ a.attachment.value.url }}
            {{ a.attachment.html_name }}

            <div class="preview">
              <div class="action">
                <span class="icon-hospital">Add Image</span>
              </div>
                <img src="{% thumbnail a.attachment.value 400x400 autocrop=False %}" alt="">
              <input class="upload-media" name="{{ a.attachment.html_name }}" type="file" value="{{ a.attachment.name }}" multiple>
              <input type="hidden" class="files-to-exclude">
            </div>

            <div class="description">
              <div class="filename">{{ a.attachment.value.name }}</div>
              <div class="filesize">{{ a.attachment.value.size }}</div>
              <ul class="btn-group">
                <li class="download">
                  <a class="button icon-download-alt" href="{{ a.attachment.value.url }}" target="_blank"></a>
                </li>
              {% if formset.can_delete and 'can_edit_posts' in perm_list %}
                <li class="delete">
                  {{ a.DELETE }}
                  <label for="{{a.DELETE.auto_id}}" class="button icon-trash"></label>
                </li>
              {% endif %}
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="previews"></div>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This is my `self.request.POST`:

```
<QueryDict: {u'FILES_4958-1-post_locale': [u'4958'], u'version': [u'1498653534877609:i1YC3hX-ReN2ZbdsDx4r8-eKGkQ', u'1498653534877609:i1YC3hX-ReN2ZbdsDx4r8-eKGkQ'], u'FILES_4959-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'1'], u'FILES_4958-4-post_locale': [u'4958'], u'FILES_4958-3-post_locale': [u'4958'], u'locales-0-id': [u'4958'], u'pub_date_1': [u'00:00'], u'pub_date_0': [u'29/06/2017'], u'FILES_4958-0-attachment': [u''], u'calendar': [u'33'], u'FILES_4958-3-attachment': [u''], u'FILES_4958-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'4'], u'promoted_to_0': [u'29/06/2017'], u'promoted_to_1': [u'00:00'], u'FILES_4959-0-post_locale': [u'4959'], u'FILES_4958-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'5'], u'FILES_4958-2-id': [u'4506'], u'promoted_from_1': [u'00:00'], u'theme': [u''], u'locales-TOTAL_FORMS': [u'2'], u'promoted_from_0': [u'29/06/2017'], u'FILES_4959-0-attachment': [u''], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'4pbI4tpoAiX5Fvms4kt424OZjFg1VNpH'], u'FILES_4958-3-id': [u'4507'], u'status': [u'0'], u'locales-0-locale': [u'60'], u'FILES_4958-1-attachment': [u''], u'locales-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'2'], u'FILES_4958-2-attachment': [u''], u'FILES_4959-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u'1000'], u'locales-0-description': [u''], u'locales-1-description': [u''], u'FILES_4959-0-id': [u''], u'FILES_4958-1-id': [u'4505'], u'promoted_budget': [u''], u'locales-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u'1000'], u'locales-1-id': [u'4959'], u'FILES_4959-INITIAL_FORMS': [u'0'], u'FILES_4958-4-id': [u''], u'FILES_4958-2-post_locale': [u'4958'], u'FILES_4958-0-id': [u'4504'], u'locales-1-locale': [u'59'], u'FILES_4958-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [u'1000'], u'FILES_4958-0-post_locale': [u'4958'], u'delete': [u'', u'']}>
```

Here is my: self.request.FILES

```
<MultiValueDict: {u'FILES_4958-4-attachment': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: 14997117_765697240238061_1697922175_n.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: 16010645_1347977721942284_325286987_o.jpg (image/jpeg)>]}>
```

Here is `form_valid` method in my view:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = self.request.user
        post.save()
        setattr(self, "post", post)

        PostLocaleFormset = inlineformset_factory(Post, PostLocale, formset=BasePostLocaleFormset)
        formset = PostLocaleFormset(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES, queryset=post.locales.all(), instance=post)

        if formset.is_valid():
            for f in formset:
                if f.is_valid() and not f.empty_permitted:
                    locale = formset.save_new(f)
            locales = formset.save_all()

        return super(BasePostEdit, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: `self.request.FILES` correctly contains two files. I think your problem is that you are creating the `PostLocaleFormset` with the request data and a queryset. Try to initialize the formset with either the request `POST` and `DATA` **if** the HTTP method is POST, and use the queryset when is a HTTP GET

Comment: @alfonso.kim I did like this:         `if self.request.method == 'POST':
            formset = PostLocaleFormset(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES, instance=post)
        elif self.request.method == 'GET':
            formset = PostLocaleFormset(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES, queryset=post.locales.all(),
                                        instance=post)` but dosen't work

Comment: hum. also remove the `instance`: `self.request.method == 'POST': formset = PostLocaleFormset(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES) elif self.request.method == 'GET': formset = PostLocaleFormset(queryset=post.locales.all())`

Comment: Nope I got index out of range

Comment: well, I guess that there is the error: Django is trying to retrieve two forms where there is only one. Please try to inspect every form within the formset before and after the validation to see where you are loosing one form.